# Are unsigned long types available to LibreOffice Basic?

Tags: libreoffice, basic

I'm want to write a simple 32-bit [FNV hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) for LibreOffice Calc. However, [LibreOffice Basic only supports signed long data types](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Numbers), so you will get an "Inadmissible value or data type. Overflow." error on line 7 with the following code:

```
Function Hash(strText as String) as Long
    Dim h As Long
    Dim nextChar As String
    Dim temp As Long

    h = 2166136261

    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        nextChar = Mid(strText, i, 1)

        temp = Asc(nextChar)
        h = h XOR temp
        h = h * 16777619
    Next

    Hash = h
End Function
```

Because the `h` variable is assigned 2166136261 in the code above, it is obviously out of bounds. Is it possible to work with unsigned long (0 to 4294967295) data types in LibreOffice Basic? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```vb
Sub CallHash
    oMasterScriptProviderFactory = createUnoService(_
        "com.sun.star.script.provider.MasterScriptProviderFactory")
    oScriptProvider = oMasterScriptProviderFactory.createScriptProvider("")
    oScript = oScriptProvider.getScript(_
        "vnd.sun.star.script:foo.py$hash?language=Python&location=user")
    hashString = oScript.invoke(Array("bar"), Array(), Array())
    MsgBox hashString
End Sub
```

foo.py:

```
def hash(strText):
    h = 2166136261
    for nextChar in strText:
        temp = ord(nextChar)
        h = h ^ temp
        h = h * 16777619
    return str(h)
```

Or drop Basic and use only Python-UNO.

There are unsigned long values in the UNO API. However, I didn't find any API methods to perform calculations on this object.

```
Dim o As Object
o = CreateUnoValue("unsigned long", 2166136261)
```